# Automatically wrap abritrary-length text in graphics

Tags: graphics

**Question:** How to insert `Style`d text of unknown style and length into a graphics and have it wrap at a `Scaled` width?

**Attempt:** I found the following two ways to wrap text when I was googling:

```
(* Based on: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Mar/msg00977.html *)
syd[txt_, w_: 100, h_: 50] := 
 Graphics[{Inset[Framed@txt, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {w, h}]}]

(* Based on: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Mar/msg00916.html *)
fred[txt_, w_: 150] := Graphics[{
   Inset[Framed@Pane[Style[txt, LineIndent -> 0, TextAlignment -> Left], w], {0, 0}]
   }]
```

But I want to handle text of unknown length so I did this to Syds solution:

```
(* Since {w,h}={100,50} worked for a string of length 460
it's reasonable to assume each character needs (100*50)/460 area units,
so any string should have area of StringLength[txt]*(100*50)/460 \
since w is given let 
h=StringLength[txt]*(100*50)/(460*w)
*)
sydGuessHeight[txt_, w_: 100] := 
 Graphics[{Inset[
    Framed@txt, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {w, 
     StringLength[txt]*(100*50)/(460*w)}]}, 
  PlotLabel -> Style["syd guess: w=" <> ToString[w], Red, Bold]]
```

A test:

```
txt1 = (StringJoin @@ 
    Table["The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. ", {10}]);
txt2 = (StringJoin @@ 
    Table["The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. ", {20}]);
Grid[Partition[Image /@ {
    syd[txt1],
    syd[txt2],
    syd[txt2, 100, Automatic] ,
    fred[txt1],
    fred[txt2],
    sydGuessHeight[txt2]}, 2]]
```

[image]

This is all very inelegant and I still can't use it to wrap text of a `Scaled` width nor can I supply `Style`d text since any modification in font will break the guess.

Comment: For "unknown length" do you want a scroll bar?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov No, I just want it to grow in height (preferably downwards)

Comment: @ssch I presume you tried playing with Pane[txt1,ImagesizeAction->"ResizeToFit"]?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using Framed@txt you can use Framed@TextCell then you can resize and format ect.

```
sydGuessHeight2[txt_, w_: 100] := Graphics[{Inset[
    Framed@TextCell[
      Style[txt, LineIndent -> 0, TextAlignment -> Left], "Text", 
      CellMargins -> {{200, 200}, {10, 10}}], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {w, 
     StringLength[txt]*(100*50)/(460*w)}]}, 
  PlotLabel -> Style["syd guess: w=" <> ToString[w], Red, Bold]]

txt2 = (StringJoin @@ 
    Table["The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. ", {20}]);
sydGuessHeight2[txt2, 50]
```

[image: The output]